# Filter function in R is throwing error " Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. x object 'batting_team' not found"

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame ball_by_ball through IPL dataset and I want to get total runs scored by Royal Challengers Bangalore in different overs of the game. I tried this code but it's throwing an error " Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. x object 'batting_team' not found".

```
***ball_by_ball%>%
    select(over,total_runs)%>%
    filter(batting_team %in% "Royal Challengers Bangalore")%>%
    group_by(over)%>%
    tally(sort = T)***
```

Please help me out what's wrong with this code! I tried detaching "DPLYR" and loading it again but didn't work well.

Comment: `ball_by_ball%>% select(over,total_runs)%>%  filter(batting_team %in% "Royal Challengers Bangalore")%>%  group_by(over) %>% summarise(total_runs = sum(total_runs))`

Comment: Hi @RonakShah, I'm still getting this error: "Error: Problem with filter() input ..1. x object 'batting_team' not found".